# Getting no such element exception when I am using @FindBy annotation, working fine when I used driver.findelement(By.id())

Tags: java, appium, appium-android, pageobjects

I am using java with appium.
I executed my code using 2 ways.
**One -when I am using below code it is working fine.**

```
public class On_BoardingPages

    MobileElement smsField = driver.findElement(By.id("pinEntryViewVerifyCode"));
    smsField.sendKeys("XXXX");


    public On_BoardingPages(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);

    }
    public void enterSMSVerificationCode(String codeVerification) { 
        sms_VerificationCode.sendKeys(codeVerification);

    }
```

**Second- When I am using POM and its failing**

page class:

```
@FindBy(id = "pinEntryViewVerifyCode")
private MobileElement sms_VerificationCode;
```

TestClass

```
on_BoardingPages.enterSMSVerificationCode("XXXX");
```

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.chained({By.id: pinEntryViewVerifyCode})
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:126)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:60)
>   --Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction@56a4479a (tried for 1 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:303)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:271)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:99)
>       at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:119)

Answer (score 0):

@FindBy will work only for WebElements POM. For MobileElements we should use **@AndroidFindBy** for android and **@iOSXCUITFindBy** for iOS.

So your code will look like:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "pinEntryViewVerifyCode")
private MobileElement sms_VerificationCode;
```

Comment: You can also set a breakpoint where the test is failing and use the "Evaluate Expression" command `(alt + f8)` to check whether or not `driver.findElement(MobileBy.id("pinEntryViewVerifyCode"));` will work

Comment: Yes it worked with find by, but I used @androidFindBy because its an android element.Issue was wait here